# How to return normal characters from JSON JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I get a json from my post with title like this:

```
"title":{"rendered":"Web Designer &#038; All things you should to know."}
```

I use like this to get post title.

```
post.title.rendered
```

but it returns `&#038;` instead of `&`

How can I get normal string only.

Comment: please add a [mcve] to your question. without knowing how you use the JSON (to your HTML) it's hard to give a definite answer

Comment: @ochi it is quite detail. You can see JSON contains `&#038;` instead of `&`. So I need to process to return only `& `

Comment: If you're using PHP, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17665909/convert-038-back-to-ampersand) might be helpful.

Comment: @31piy I am developer App via API so I need to use Javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`DomParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) is pretty well supported these days. It's seems like overkill, but you could just parse it:

```js
let post = {
  "title": {
    "rendered": "Web Designer &#038; All things you should to know."
  }
}

let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(post.title.rendered, "text/html");
console.log(doc.body.textContent)
```

It's not clear from your question why you need to do this (although I'm not really familiar with Wordpress). If you are going to use this text within web content, it should work as is. For example:

```js
 let post = {
      "title": {
        "rendered": "Web Designer &#038; All things you should to know."
      }
    }
   
 document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = post.title.rendered
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This JavaScript parses HTML entities:

```
let div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = post.title.rendered;
let text = div.textContent;
```

If you need it in WordPress PHP, 31py's suggestion of `html_entity_decode` is the way to go.